# TypeError when trying to calculate age

Tags: python

Been playing around on Code Academy and learnt some basics and have started reading "The Hard Way to Learn Python".

I'm just playing around trying to get familiar with functions and syntax and am stuck on a simple bit of code I'm writing- see below.

I get the following error for the line = "next_birth"- What am I doing wrong? I'm simply trying to +1 to "age" but obviously not going about it the correct way!

```
File "p.py", line 17, in <module>
    next_birth= age + 1
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

---

```
print "Hello there "
original = raw_input('What is your name? ')

if len(original) > 0:

    print "Hello "+original
else:
    print "Okay, your shy, dont tell me your name"

age=raw_input("How old are you? ")
if age >"25":
    print "Thats old....."
else:
    print "Your a spring chicken....."

birthday=raw_input("When is your birthday? ")

next_birth= age + 1

print "Ok, Happy" + next_birth + "Birthday for then. Nice talking to you, have a nice day"
```

Answer (score 2):

`age` is a string (`raw_input()` always returns strings), and `1` is an integer. You cannot add the two together.

Turn `age` into an integer instead:

```
next_birth = int(age) + 1
```

but you want to do that as early as possible really:

```
age=int(raw_input("How old are you? "))
if age > 25:
    print "Thats old....."
else:
    print "Your a spring chicken....."
```

because comparing *strings* compares them alphabetically. `"8"` is also greater than `"25"` because alphabetically, `8` comes after `2`. If you typed in `"100"` on the other hand, you'd get the wrong answer as well, as `1` sorts *before* `2`. When comparing integers you get the correct answers here.

When printing, use commas:

```
print "Ok, Happy", next_birth, "Birthday for then. Nice talking to you, have a nice day"
```

so that `print` will automatically turn the integer value for `next_birth` into a string again.

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input()` returns a string. You'll have to convert it to an integer first before you compare it or try to concatenate it with other integers.

To do this, you use the `int()` function:

```
age = int(raw_input("How old are you? "))
```

Note that this will fail if you input something other than a number.

It's also not recommended to compare a string with a string, using an operator such as the "is greater than". Change your string `"25"` to an integer `25`

Comment: Excellent thanks. Looks great now: print "Hello there "
original = raw_input('What is your name? ')
if len(original) > 0:
    
    print "Hello "+original
else:
    print "Okay, your shy, dont tell me your name"

age=int(raw_input("How old are you? "))
if age >25:
 print "Thats old....."
else:
 print "Your a spring chicken....."

birthday=raw_input("When is your birthday? ")

next_birth= age+1

print "Ok, Happy", next_birth, "Birthday for then. Nice talking to you, have a nice day"

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that `age` is a string (because it was typed at the input). You need to convert it to a number.

For example:

```
age = int(age)
```

Now it is a number not a string... Python is weird like that with data types. You will get used to it.

By the way - once you have `age` as an integer you need to do your comparisons with integers - for example

```
if age > 25:
```

Instead of

```
if age > "25":
```

The latter compares things "lexically" - how they would appear in a dictionary. Thus "100"<"2" for example (1 comes before 2 in the dictionary).